# How to fix view of broken images?

Tags: images, mms

Sometimes people MMS images to me from their phone, and it shows up like this:
[image]

When I save the broken image, and transfer it to my computer, it displays properly on my computer. Is there a way to get these images to display properly on my phone? I'm running Android 4.0.4 with stock messaging app.